# How to get page name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to get the current page name in wordpress.Here is example http://ww.example.com/media/.
How do we get the font_page.php.Please help me.

```
$page_data = get_page($postid);
echo $page_data->post_title;
```

The above example displays title of page.we need the font_page.php.How can we get this.

Comment: User `var_dump` to print `$page_data`. Check what values you are getting from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the file name of your template file.
You may use `get_page_template()` for get the template file name:

```
echo basename( get_page_template() );

//it will return your template file name
```